# Can you specify a linear system to estimate the axes of this ellipsoid?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the ellipsoid $x^2/r_x + y^2/r_y + y^2/r_z = 1$ that is centered at the origin,
can you specify the linear system to estimate $r_x$, $r_y$, and $r_z$ from $n$ points? And if you can, how many points would you need in order to over-constrain the system?

Comment: Hint: define $a_k=1/r_k$.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are three variables $1\over r_x$, $1\over r_y$, $1\over r_z$, you will need three independent equations for finding them, that is $$\begin{bmatrix}x_1^2&y_1^2&z_1^2\\ x_2^2&y_2^2&z_2^2\\ x_3^2&y_3^2&z_3^2\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}{1\over r_x}\\{1\over r_y}\\{1\over r_z}\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ are points of the ellipsoid chosen such that the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}x_1^2&y_1^2&z_1^2\\ x_2^2&y_2^2&z_2^2\\ x_3^2&y_3^2&z_3^2\end{bmatrix}$ is invertible.

Comment: Square the coordinates !

Comment: Oops! Thanks for mentioning that typo.

Comment: The particular shape of the determinant shows that it is useless that add points differing only by the sign of some coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider a transformed space made of the points $(x^2,y^2,z^2)$ your ellipsoid turns to a triangle that cuts the axis at the points $(r_x,0,0), (0,r_y,0)$ and $(0,0,r_z)$*. This plane can be determined by solving a $3\times3$ linear system, knowing three points (vectorially, the normal to the plane is given by $\vec{p_0p_1}\times \vec{p_0p_2}$).

You can add more points and solve the plane equation by least-squares.

---

*If you revert to standard coordinates, the triangle is one eighth of the ellipsoid and the other patches appear by symmetry.